# Reading Smart Card from Omnikey 5427 CK in Android

Tags: android, smartcard

Scenario : 
Need to read SmartCard using Android .

I am trying to make an App in  Android to read smartcard using 5427 SmartCard reader . I have attached that reader using OTG/ USB  . From Play Store i have downloaded this app ATR Analyzer and it reads the card with success . I want to make similar Application  but couldnt find any clue As the library being used by app below is not available 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.scdroid.atranalyzer&hl=en

On Windows I am able to make an application using java javax-smartcardio it works fine . Also i am able to make application in C# .net console based that reads the card .

Ive searched all over the place javax-smartcardio cant be used in android as i found.

There is another option of using java with raspberry Pi to achieve the same result as well any how android seems more suitable to me as per my requirement

Comment: it will be hard to explain whole process of using card reader in Android for anyone in SO. Better if you can discuss a specific issue that you are facing with regard to card reader!

Comment: i want to connect with my reader through otg thats what i want to do

Comment: @AbdulBasit Did you ever find a working solution to this for Android?

Comment: @AbdulBasit Have you found a solution for the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Go through the [CCID protocol specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/DWG_Smart-Card_CCID_Rev110.pdf) which describes how to communicate with the smartcard reader via USB and the [Android USB Host documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) which describes how to do the USB communication in Android.

Basically every smart card reader support a minimum of two endpoints in addition to the default (control) endpoint: one bulk-out and one bulk-in.

[image]

The image show the endpoint information of Omnikey 5427 CK reader.

Comment: I need a guide or sample code to connect with my usb card reader ? can you help with it

Comment: First, you should read the document and try to understand the basic concept.paste a code here is not a good idea..Do some research on it and edit your question with your effort.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the device connection with the help of interface
which is provided by `UsbDevice` class and get the interface of device via `getInterface()` then use `UsbDeviceConnection` class and call the `claimInterface()` to claim the interface .

Then you can connect your reader with the OTG cable to the android device.

Comment: which library youre talking about ?

Comment: ok i am able to read my device information through that  Thanks . But now how can i communicate with it to read the card ?

Comment: you have to go through the ccid rev 1.0 document and transmit the data through the bulkTransfer() . this is a long process i am can`t able to tell you there.